# Extracting text from archived Outlook messages

Tags: perl, shell, outlook

In an Outlook folder, I store hundreds of messages about the status of a battery system. The emails are automatically sent daily. Each message contains information on the battery voltage in the message body, and the information is always formatted as follows,
DATE: 9/14/2011
Main Battery Voltage [V]:  25.67

I would like to write a routine to extract the battery voltage and date information from each message body and concatenate the results so I get a vector of [date, voltage]. I'd like the routine to run from the command line, rather than using Outlook. What is the right tool for this task? Are Outlook messages in a specific folder saved as ASCII files somewhere? If that is the case, I could easily open all the files using perl or similar tool and pull the information out. I just don't know how and where the message body information is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bypass Outlook entirely, you could use `IMAP::Client` or somesuch to fetch the mail directly from the server. Depending on how Outlook was configured, existing messages may or may not be there, but it'll work for all new messages, anyway.

Comment: Will messages still be accessible from Outlook too? thanks for useful suggestion

Comment: That again depends on how you use `IMAP::Client`. Anything that interfaces with the email server, and has permissions on the server, can delete messages if its asked to do so. In Outlook's case, people often create local folders for message filters, which will delete the messages on the server when they're moved locally.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your Outlook message store into a standard formats like Maildir or Mbox first, then employ [`Email::Folder`](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aFolder) or [`Mail::Box`](http://p3rl.org/Mail%3a%3aBox) for the parsing.